# qemu arm64 emulation on host x86, it stuck when booting kernel

Tags: qemu, emulation, arm64

I am trying to emulate ARM architecture using QEMU. My host OS is ubuntu 16.04 and the guest OS inside the emulated machine is also ubuntu 16.04. Hardware specifications of my host system are:

- Processor: x86 host
- Memory: 16 GiB
- OS-type: 64 bit
- Disk 500 GB

I followed those links:
 - https://community.ubuntu.com/
 - https://wiki.linaro.org/LEG/UEFIforQEMU

When I follow these steps, it launches a shell, and is stuck at Linux booting:

```
UEFI Interactive Shell v2.287477C2-69C7-11D2-8E39-00A0C969723B 138FF62A0
EDK IIlProtocolInterface: 752F3136-4E16-4FDC-A22A-E5F46812F4CA 138FF1018
UEFI v2.60 (EDK II, 0x00010000)008-7F9B-4F30-87AC-60C9FEF5DA4E 13831C710
Mapping table
      FS0: Alias(s):HD1b:;BLK2:
          VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003E000A00000000)/HD(1,MBR,0x00000000,0x3F,0x25FC0)
     BLK4: Alias(s):
          VenHw(F9B94AE2-8BA6-409B-9D56-B9B417F53CB3)
     BLK0: Alias(s):
          VenHw(8047DB4B-7E9C-4C0C-8EBC-DFBBAACACE8F)
     BLK1: Alias(s):
          VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003E000A00000000)
     BLK3: Alias(s):
          VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003E000A00000000)/HD(2,MBR,0x00000000,0x26000,0x5DA000)


Press ESC in 1 seconds to skip startup.nsh or any other key to continue.
FSOpen: Open '\efi\boot\startup.nsh' Success
FSOpen: Open '\efi\boot\startup.nsh' Success
FSOpen: Open '\efi\boot\startup.nsh' Success
Shell> Image dtb=fvp-base-gicv2-psci.dtb console=ttyAMA0,38400n8 earlyprintk=pl011,0x1c090000 debug uefi_debug ignore_loglevel rootwait root=/dev/vda2 rootfstype=ext4 rw
FSOpen: Open '\Image' Success
FSOpen: Open '\Image' Success
FSOpen: Open '\Image' Success
FSOpen: Open '\Image' Success
FatDiskIo: Cache Page OutBound occurred! 
[Security] 3rd party image[0] can be loaded after EndOfDxe: VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003E000A00000000)/HD(1,MBR,0x00000000,0x3F,0x25FC0)/\Image.
InstallProtocolInterface: 5B1B31A1-9562-11D2-8E3F-00A0C969723B 138FA0040
Loading driver at 0x00136A9F000 EntryPoint=0x001374DE560
Loading driver at 0x00136A9F000 EntryPoint=0x001374DE560 
InstallProtocolInterface: BC62157E-3E33-4FEC-9920-2D3B36D750DF 138FA0E98
ProtectUefiImageCommon - 0x38FA0040
  - 0x0000000136A9F000 - 0x0000000000C12000
!!!!!!!!  ProtectUefiImageCommon - CodeSegmentCount is 0  !!!!!!!!
InstallProtocolInterface: 752F3136-4E16-4FDC-A22A-E5F46812F4CA 13EAEB740
EFI stub: Booting Linux Kernel...
FSOpen: Open 'fvp-base-gicv2-psci.dtb' Success
ConvertPages: range 13EAC0000 - 13EACFFFF covers multiple entries
EFI stub: Using DTB from command line
EFI stub: Exiting boot services and installing virtual address map...
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x000000013BD60000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x000000013BD10000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x000000013BC20000 - 0x00000000000E0000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x0000000138690000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x00000001385F0000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x0000000138550000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
SetUefiImageMemoryAttributes - 0x00000001384B0000 - 0x0000000000040000 (0x0000000000000008)
```

i am not able to figure out why it stuck like this. 
any suggestion how to resolve it?